# IIS6 Metabase Compatiblity not installing correctly for Vista IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2010, metabase

I've been bashing my head against this one for a few days, and haven't had any luck with it. I'm unable to get my VS2010 ASP.NET project to deploy to IIS. I receive the error

"Unable to create the virtual directory. To access local IIS Web sites, you must install the following IIS Components

IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility
ASP.NET

In addition, you must run Visual Studio in the context of an Administrator Account"

I've most certainly installed the metabase option, but it still shows up. I'm also not sure why it's telling me to install ASP.NET.

Google is being entirely unhelpful, I was wondering if anyone here has any suggestions. I'm running Vista Ultimate 64Bit

Comment: I think I see the problem here, I see "Vista" in your question :)  Seriously though, try uninstalling and reinstalling the full IIS6 compatibility section and re-run `aspnet_regiis -i` from your `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\versionDesriedHere\` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You've started VS2010 with 'run as Administrator', otherwise you might not have enough rights to do such a thing.
Also, the virtual dir doesn't already exist within the default IIS website?

Comment: Visual studio has the option or creating he virtual directory *for you*, this is the part that's failing, it needs the IIS6 API installed to be able to.

Comment: I know, but if you don't have admin priviliges, you won't be able to do it. At least I wasn't able to do it a couple of times because of this reason.

Answer (score 0):

This article describes "Using Visual Studio 2008 with IIS 7" but the principles likely apply to VS2010 and Vista also. [http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/using-visual-studio-with-iis/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis][1]
I am using both VS2005 & VS2010 to develop websites that use a deployment project, which creates a setup.exe and project.msi files. I wanted to know why IIS 6 Metabase compatibility is required, but still do not really understand it. If absent, the installer quits very early with a message that the installation was 'not installed correctly', nothing more. It seems like a kludge between existing MS development tools and IIS 7.